# Javascript ways or Method(s) to get adjacent characters in string

Tags: javascript, methods, split, expression

Trying to get adjacent characters in a string including blank spaces.  the 3 characters to the left and the 3 characters to the right...

maybe using regular expressions and JavaScript split() to get adjacent characters in string?

```
var str   = "one two three four five",
array     = str.split("");
```

but missing the blank spaces and the 3 character to the left and the 3 characters to the right...

any suggestions?

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: Three characters to the left and right of **what** ?

Comment: So are you saying, given a character or index in a string, find the location and get 3 chars to the left and 3 chars to the right?

Comment: Your code splits as it should, every character including spaces. And I can only second Pointy's comment without further clarification.

Comment: ie string of'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven'  

 say if an applied hover function on the string is at the 'tw' near  the two' ... the left/right adjacent would be 'ne ' tw 'o th'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try JS substring

Something like this

```
var str="Hello world!";
document.write(str.substring(3)+"<br />");
document.write(str.substring(3,7));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Or something like finding position

http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos:545

Comment: that would be ok... and I think substrings don't delete the blanks as the split does.  ultimately I am looking to write code that will work to allow the cursor to hover over the string of characters and then 'copy' those adjacent characters into another div.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a combination of indexOf and substr

Here's an example function that returns an object containing left, right and error (if any)

```
    function findSurrounding(needle, haystack, leadingCharacters, trailingCharacters){
        var pos = haystack.indexOf(needle);
        var returnObject = {'left':'', 'right':'', 'error':null};

        //if needle was not found, output error
        if(pos == -1){
            returnObject.error = needle + ' could not be found!';

        //otherwise set "left" and "right"
        } else {
            returnObject.left = haystack.substr(pos - leadingCharacters, leadingCharacters);
            returnObject.right = haystack.substr(pos + needle.length, trailingCharacters);
        }
        return returnObject;
    }
    //get output:
    var surrounding = findSurrounding('three', 'one two three four five', 3, 3)
    //debug / write output
    for(prop in surrounding){
        document.write(prop+': '+surrounding[prop]+'<br/>');
    }
```

output of this is

```
left: wo 
right:  fo
error: null
```

Hope that helps (additionally hope I understood your question!)

Comment: thanks, I will try your sample.  I meant... ie string of'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven' say if an applied hover function on the string is at the 'tw' near the two' ... the left/right adjacent would be 'ne ' tw 'o th'

Comment: part 1...<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScriptDemo/js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScriptDemo/js/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

Comment: part dos...    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
      var str       = "one two three four five",
          array     = str.split(" ");
          viewPort  = $('<div />', { id: 'stringToView' });
      for(var objId in array) {
        var obj = $('<span/>', { text: array[objId] }).hover(function() {
          var clone = $(this).clone();
          $('#magnifyView').html(clone);
        }).appendTo(viewPort);
      }
      $('body').prepend(viewPort);
    })
    </script>

Comment: part 3... <style type="text/css">
 body {
  font-family:"Tiresias PCfont Z";
  /* font-size:15px; */
        background: #fff;
        line-height:1.1em;
}
 .draggable { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
 #draggable { margin-bottom:20px; }
 
 #MagDrag {background-image:url(controls/MagLens1.png);
        width: 236px;
        height: 73px; }
 #containment-wrapper { width: 95%; height:150px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;}
 </style>

Comment: part four... <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
   $("#magnifyView").draggable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper', scroll: false, axis: 'x' });
 });
 </script>

Comment: part cinco...  </head>
  <body>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div id='magnifyView' class="draggable ui-widget-content" style="background-image:url(controls/MagLens1.png);width: 212px;height: 50px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 40px; font-weight:bold;"> what's here</div>
    

</div>

  </body>
</html>

Comment: in the above, .split splits the array but excludes blank spaces.  then applies a hover function but I am trying to achieve retaining the blanks and also getting the adjacent characters, hmmm...

Comment: @windsurf88, see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer here because I believe my original answer really does answer your question as stated (how to get adjacent characters).

However after you posted your code I see you want to create a magnifier.  That's kinda a different kettle of fish so I rewrote your code.

The reason it's different is then you need to use the mouseover to get individual letters and that means you must encapsulate individual letters into tags.  The code posted does that (essentially a working version of your code.)  Note I didn't mess with your draggable.  If you're having issues with that time for a new question.

```
<style type="text/css">
        body { font-family:"Tiresias PCfont Z"; /* font-size:15px; */ background: #fff; line-height:1.1em; }
        .draggable { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
        #draggable { margin-bottom:20px; }
        #MagDrag {background-image:url(controls/MagLens1.png); width: 236px; height: 73px; }
        #containment-wrapper { width: 95%; height:150px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; display:none;}
        #magnifyView { width: 90px;
            background-image:url(controls/MagLens1.png);width: 212px;height: 50px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 40px; font-weight:bold;
        }
        .onText { color:#990000;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScriptDemo/js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScriptDemo/js/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        //custom "magnify" function
        var mag = function(){
            return {
                add: function(){
                    //encapsulate #article into individual spans
                    //why?  mouseover events are triggered by tags, not individual letters
                    var str = $('#article').text();
                    var output = '';
                    for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
                        output += '<span>' + str.substr(i, 1) + '</span>';
                    }
                    //replace #article with altered html
                    $('#article').html(output);

                    //add the mouseover
                    $('#article span').mouseover(function(){
                        //note both these selectors could be way more efficient
                        //however this should get you started...
                        var leading = $(this).prev().add($(this).prev().prev()).add($(this).prev().prev().prev());
                        var trailing = $(this).next().add($(this).next().next()).add($(this).next().next().next());

                        $('#magnifyView').html(
                            $(leading).text() +
                            '<span class="onText">' + $(this).text() + '</span>' +
                            $(trailing).text()
                        );
                    });
                    $('#containment-wrapper').show();
                },
                remove: function(){
                    $('#article span').unbind('mouseover');
                    $('#article').html($('#article').text());
                    $('#containment-wrapper').hide();
                }
            }
        }();

        // jquery $ function load
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.addmag').click(function(){
                mag.add();
            });
            $('.removemag').click(function(){
                mag.remove();
            });
            $("#magnifyView").draggable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper', scroll: false, axis: 'x' });
        });
    </script>
```

Note, you'll need to click the "addmag" or "removemag" to add or remove the magnifier functionality.  (This is there to demonstrate how to encapsulate a string using jquery and a basic loop as well as how to get the original string back, preserving spaces etc.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: well I have successfully not implemented the above well. see here at http://soundimage.com/jbenson/jb2.html

Comment: Thanks, now I have it implemented better... now onto the drag. so transferring the function of the drag onto the graphic lens and not just the mouse cursor.